# Would Thanos be considered an anti-villain?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

Through all the horrible conquests and murders Thanos has committed through blind ambition for a better world, he does have one ounce of humanity with Gamora, as seen in *Avengers: Infinity War*. Would this alone be enough to label him as an anti-villain?

Comment: He killed a lot of people **before** executing his "just" plan. He is definitely a villain.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir from his point of view, he is **not** a villain, but a guy who're willing to do just the right thing necessary. so can't be sure how to label him. This question is whole lot bigger opinion based than Tony Stark's ego ;)

Comment: Isn't the right term "anti-hero"

Comment: @KharoBangdo in this context, I think not

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on your definition, but **yes, it is possible to describe him in this way.**

And Anti-Villain can be defined as "a villain with heroic goals, personality traits, and/or virtues" and Thanos fits into this. **Although we shouldn't dismiss the "Villain" part, he has good intentions and is at his heart just trying to do what he believes is best for the universe (even if it's not what's actually best for the universe)**

Comment: `even if it's not what's actually best for the universe` who decides this? I believe only time can. And until then one should do what he believes is correct.

Comment: @SubirKumarSao Nicely poetic there

Comment: **even if it's not what's actually best for the universe** it's from Human's point of view, Thanos has different point of view. Potatoes has a different one. Skrulls may have different one. So this is whole lot of opinion based..

Comment: With that mindset there is no real Villain because they are all Anti-Villains. Red Scull just wanted unified world. Loki just wanted his adopted father love. Hela just wanted to spend time with her brothers. Ultron wanted similar thing to Thanos and Red Scull.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY where did you get that *Hela just wanted to spend time with her brothers* thing? didn't she wanted her father's approval and support for who she really are? and claims what's rightfully hers? Where the brothers thing come from? Did I missed that?

Comment: @Vishwa It's a joke. Based on the fact that among these three sibling Thor is the "odd" one.